# How to implement kmeans clustering as a feature for classification techniques in SVM?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, k-means

Ive already created a clustering and saved the model but im confused what should i do with this model and how to use it as a feature for classification.
This clustering is based on the coordinate of a crime place. after the data has been clustered, i want to use the clustered model as features in SVM.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import numpy as np
import xlrd

import pickle
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import *

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (16, 9)
plt.style.use('ggplot')

#kmeans section 
#Creating and labelling latitudes of X and Y and plotting it 
data=pd.read_excel("sanfrancisco.xlsx")
x1=data['X']
y1=data['Y']
X = np.array(list(zip(x1,y1)))

# Elbow method 

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans 
wcss = [] #empty string
# to check in range for 10 cluster
for i in range(1,11): 
        kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=i, init='k-means++') # will generate centroids 
        kmeans.fit(X)
        wcss.append(kmeans.inertia_) # to find euclidean distance

plot1 = plt.figure(1)
plt.xlabel("Number of Clusters")
plt.ylabel("Euclidean Distance")
plt.plot(range(1,11), wcss)

k = 3


# data visual section.. Eg: how many crimes in diff month, most number of crime in a day in a week 
# most number crime in what address, most number of crimes in what city, how many crime occur 
# in how much time. , etc..

# X coordinates of random centroids 
C_x = np.random.randint(0, np.max(X)-20, size=k)
# Y coordinates of random centroids
C_y = np.random.randint(0, np.max(X)-20, size=k)
C = np.array(list(zip(C_x,C_y)), dtype=np.float32)
print("Initial Centroids")
print(C)


# n_clustersr takes numbers of clusters, init chooses random data points for the initial centroids 
# in default sckit provides 10 times of count and chooses the best one, in order to elak n_init assigned to 1
model = KMeans(n_clusters=k, init='random', n_init=1)
model.fit_transform(X)
centroids = model.cluster_centers_ # final centroids

rgb_colors = {0.: 'y',
                  1.: 'c',
                  2.: 'fuchsia',
                  }
if k == 4:
        rgb_colors[3.] = 'lime'
if k == 6:
        rgb_colors[3.] = 'lime'
        rgb_colors[4.] = 'orange'
        rgb_colors[5.] = 'tomato'

new_labels = pd.Series(model.labels_.astype(float)) # label that predicted by kmeans

plot2 = plt.figure(2)
plt.scatter(x1, y1, c=new_labels.map(rgb_colors), s=20)
plt.scatter(centroids[:, 0], centroids[:, 1], marker='*', c='black', s=200 )
plt.xlabel('Final Cluster Centers\n Iteration Count=' +str(model.n_iter_)+
               '\n Objective Function Value: ' +str(model.inertia_))
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title("k-Means")
plt.show()

# save the model to disk 
filename = 'clusteredmatrix.sav'
pickle.dump(model, open(filename,'wb'))
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not much clear, but if you want to see the behavior of clusters, I recommend you to use a tool like [Weka](https://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/), so that you can freely cluster them and get meaningful inferences before going into complex coding stuff!